# About the skipValidation option of the fromSecretKey function

Tags: web3.js

I have one question

https://solanacookbook.com/references/keypairs-and-wallets.html#how-to-restore-a-keypair-from-a-secret
I would like to create a Solana keypair from an EVM private key.

```
const privateKey = 'private key'
const secretKey = Buffer.from(privateKey)
let keypair = solanaWeb3.Keypair.fromSecretKey(secretKey, {skipValidation: true});
console.log(keypair.publicKey)
console.log(keypair.secretKey)
```

The program runs to the end with no errors.
However, if the skipValidation option is set to false, the error "provided secretKey is invalid" will occur.
I understand that the process in the fromSecretKey function checks for integrity, but why bother with this option in the first place?
Also, what are the disadvantages of making this option true later on?

By the way
console.log(PublicKey.isOnCurve(key.toBytes())));
the result was true

Answer (score 0):

The secret key in question is actually the 64 bytes that result when you concatenate the public key and the private key together.

The validation step ensures that the 32 of those bytes that represent the public key are exactly that which result if you *derived* a public key from the 32 of those bytes that represent the private key.

```
// This is what validation enforces:
secretKey.slice(32, 64) === derivePublicKey(secretKey.slice(0, 32));
```

A vulnerability results, under certain circumstances, if an attacker is able to use the secret key to sign the same message twice, but to modify the public key part of those 64 bytes between signings. You can read all about that vulnerability at https://github.com/dchest/tweetnacl-js/issues/247#issuecomment-1205059990